# What are lccode and uccode used for?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, tex-core, luatex

In TeX, each of the 256 bytes has an associated `\lccode` and an `\uccode`, integers in the range [0,255] which indicate among other things how `\lowercase` and `\uppercase` act.  There are of course a bunch of other numbers (mathcode, and catcode for instance), but I am focusing here on case-changing codes.

A look at the TeXbook tells me about the following uses of the `\lccode` and `\uccode`:

- `\lowercase` *`<general text>`* turns each character token in the argument into a character token with the same category code, but a character code equal to the `\lccode` of the original character code, unless the `\lccode` is zero, in which case, the original character code is retained.
- `\uppercase` *`<general text>`* behaves in the same way, using the `\uccode` instead.
- When hyphenating, TeX takes whatever characters reached its stomach (so either from tokens with category code 11 or 12, or from chardef'd tokens, or char), and defines a "letter" to be a character with non-zero `\lccode`.  A letter is lowercase if its `\lccode` is equal to its character code.

Is this all?  In particular, does TeX use the `\uccode` for any purpose other than the `\uppercase` primitive?  What about other engines, pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX?

Comment: TeX uses also characters specified with `\char` or `\chardef` tokens when doing hyphenation (treating them if they were character tokens with category code 12); the relative `\lccode` should be nonzero, of course.

Comment: Thank you @egreg, I changed the claim here.  In fact, my earlier statement made no sense, since there are no tokens anymore at this stage of processing.

Comment: A quick look at `tex.web` shows no particular usage of `\uccode`; there's only the `\uchyph` parameter to consider, again in connection with hyphenation: if the parameter's value is less than 1, words starting with an uppercase letter c (determined by uc_code(c)=c) won't be hyphenated.

Comment: The parenthesis in egreg's comment should read "(determined by lc_code(c)<>c and lc_code(c)<>0)", as explained in `tex.web`, or in Joseph's answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\lccode` of a character is used in hyphenation when `\uchyph` is set to zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\uchyph=0 %

\begingroup
  \lccode`\C=`\C
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Capitalised word.
  \par
\endgroup

\begingroup
  \lccode`\C=`\c
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Capitalised word.
  \par
\endgroup

\begingroup
  \uccode`\C=`\C
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Capitalised word.
  \par
\endgroup

\begingroup
  \uccode`\C=`\c
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Some filler text. 
  Capitalised word.
  \par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Notice that `\uchyph` is therefore misleadingly-named, as what is tested is whether the word starts with a lower case letter (one with `\lccode` equal to itself).

Answer (score 11):

Letters inside of `\patterns` are mapped through `\lccode`.  In fact, that's the only mechanism by which one can specify hyphenation patterns including - and/or 0-9 since writing them literally will have them interpreted as hyphenation priorities or hyphenation points.

[`hypht1.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/hyphenation/hypht1.tex) mentions this trick in the starting comment section.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Thanks for your answer, we're looking forward to your future contributions to this Q&A.